# Validate date before change, in two different functions

Tags: java

I am new with Java, and all this function param/object method(Very different from PowerShell)
I want to write a simple program that represents a Date object and before each `set`, it checks if the date is valid. If it's not valid, set to default.

I am having a problem with `setDay`,`setMonth` and `setYear`(wrote only `setYear` below just for the example). `setYear` working with one param(year), and `isValidDate` working with 3 params(day,month,year). How can I call `isValidDate` in set functions?

I can't change `main`, but only `public/private` functions calls.

Set function:

```
public void setYear(int yearToSet){
    _year = isValidDate(yearToSet); //??????? PROBLEM ??????? tried:_year = isValidDate(yearToSet) ? yearToSet : DEF_YEAR;
    _year = yearToSet;   
}
```

Program:

```
public class Date {
// Private vars
private int _day;
private int _month;
private int _year;
// Private finals
private final int MIN_DAY = 1;
private final int MIN_MONTH = 1;
private final int MAX_MONTH = 12;
private final int MIN_YEAR = 1000;
private final int MAX_YEAR = 9999;
private final int DEF_DAY = 1;
private final int DEF_MONTH = 1;
private final int DEF_YEAR = 2000;

// Constructors:
/**
 * Creates a new Date object if the date is valid, otherwise creates the date 1/1/2000
 * @param day the day in the month(1-31)
 * @param month the month in the year(1-12)
 * @param year the year (4 digits)
 */
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    if (isValidDate(day,month,year)) {
        _day = day;
        _month = month;
        _year = year;
    }
    else
        defDate();
}

// Private methods
/**
 * Set date to default - 1/1/2000
 */
private void defDate(){
    setDay(DEF_DAY);
    setMonth(DEF_MONTH);
    setYear(DEF_YEAR);
}

/**
 * Validate day by month
 */
private int numDaysInMonth(int month, boolean isLeapYear) {
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
        return 31;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
        return 30;
        case 2:
        if (isLeapYear) {
            return 29;
        } else {
            return 28;
        }
        default:
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Leap year check
 */
private boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return (((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0));
}

/**
 * Date validate 
 */
private boolean isValidDate(int day, int month, int year) {
    return (month >= MIN_MONTH && month <= MAX_MONTH) && 
    (day >= MIN_DAY && day <= numDaysInMonth(month, isLeapYear(year))) && (year >= MIN_YEAR && year <= MAX_YEAR);
}

/** 
 * Sets the year (only if date remains valid)
 * @param yearToSet - the year value to be set
 */
public void setYear(int yearToSet){
    _year = isValidDate(yearToSet); //??????? PROBLEM ???????
    _year = yearToSet;   
}
```

Comment: nooooo, several classes can already do that... why trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I know, it's a project for study. We can't use those classes.

Answer (score 2):

isValidDate returns a boolean and _year is an int so you can't write:

```
_year = isValidDate(yearToSet)
```

You can write:

```
if (isValidDate(_day,_month,yearToSet) {
 _year = yearToSet;
} else {
 _year = DEF_YEAR;
}
```

or in one line:

```
_year = isValidDate(_day,_month,yearToSet) ? yearToSet : DEF_YEAR;
```

You made two mistakes:

- isValidDate needs 3 parameters (that's what you define), you can't
  call it with only one
- isValidDate returns a boolean and _year is a int, and in Java you
  can't put a boolean in an int.

Comment: Tried this. An error appears: `method isValidDate in class Date cannot be applied to given types: required int,int,int; fount: int;....`

Comment: @igor In your Question’s code, you declare the `isValidDate` method as taking three arguments (day,month,year) while inside `setYear` method you pass only a single argument (year). The Answer here by Thierry was following your lead, but your Question's code was incorrect in the number of arguments. Your line you marked `//??????? PROBLEM ???????` is indeed the problem, passing a single argument when three are required. You should have included the *exact* error message in your Question.

Comment: OP said _I am new with Java_ so this might need more explanation than just _you can't write: ..._ ;)

Comment: I agree so I had some explanation, but it's difficult to explain shortly, maybe @igor you need to read some basic about Java, like this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html